# Safari doesn't forward session cookies to JVM when requesting applet JAR

Tags: cookies, safari, applet, jvm, session-cookies

Our web app restricts access to authenticated users; our servers are configured to refuse access to any resource requests unless the HTTP request includes the session cookies. We use a Java applet, for which access to the JAR file is also prevented unless the request has the correct session cookies set.

This works fine for all major browsers we have tried on Windows clients except for Safari (don't have a Mac to test Safari on this). All page resources e.g., html, js, images, ..., load fine; except for the JAR file, where our server returns a 'not authorised' page which obviously doesn't work in the applet container.

It looks like the JVM isn't sending the session cookies when it requests the JAR. I suspect that Safari isn't sharing the cookies with the JVM, because everything works OK in other browsers with the same JVM (IE, Chrome, Fx).

Is there anything we can do to fix this? Or work around this? We can't make the JAR available to non-authorised users due to licensing issues, nor can we change the hosting environment.

Comment: Do the session cookies have `HttpOnly` set on them?

Comment: No, the session cookies don't have HttpOnly set on them in this case. Have also checked the size of all cookies and it's less than 4KB, which I understand is sometimes a problem for Safari.